# How to log to the console in react

Tags: reactjs, scroll, event-handling

I'm a beginner in react and I'm just trying to dechiper a very complex code by simply logging values like props among others.
Specifically, I need to log data every time the handleScroll method is called by an event listener. The code uses lodash for throttling.

The code goes like this, but no data gets written to the console in F12:

```
appNode = null;
  state = {
    sticky: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getQueues();
    this.appNode = getScrollableNode(this.context.renderRoot);
    if (this.appNode) {
      this.appNode.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
  }
.
.
.
handleScroll = throttle(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(`this.props: ${this.props}`));
    const {
      actions,
      query,
      page,
      hasMore,
      loadingMore,
      searchTerm,
      loading
    } = this.props;
    const scrollTop = this.appNode.scrollTop;
```

The console.log there does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it could be possible your `handleScroll` is not called at all. try console.logging in your `componentDidMount` and validate `this.appNode`. if it's okay, console.log any string such as "test" inside handleScroll and see if it's logged.

Comment: also, `JSON.stringify()` expects an object, so you'd better do `JSON.stringify(this.props)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it wasn't a problem with the logging or anything else, but with the customized component's innerworkings.